# Is there a simpler way to convert a List of Maps in a List of POJO in Java 7 using Java or Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, java-7, data-conversion

Prelude: I'm using hibernate 3 with a select that returns only some specified fields. I didn't find a way to get a list of POJOs, the best I found is to return a list of maps using `query.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);`

---

I have a list of `Map<String, Object>`. Now, the way I found to convert it to a list of POJO is with Jackson:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo myPojo;

List<myPojo> res = new ArrayList<>();

// rows is the List<Map<String, Object>>
for (Object row : rows) {
    myPojo = objectMapper.convertValue(row, MyPojo.class);
    res.add(myPojo);
}
```

Is there not a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was near, Yann :-)

I found it, thanks to [cowtowncoder](https://github.com/cowtowncoder):

```java
TypeReference<List<MyPojo>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<MyPojo>>() {/* */};
List<MyPojo> res = mapper.convertValue(rows,  typeReference);
```

Source: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/issues/89#issuecomment-882713171

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TypeReference:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyPojo> res = objectMapper.convertValue(rows, new TypeReference<MyPojo>() {});
```

Comment: This is for a single value. Eclipse tells me "Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyPojoto List<MyPojo>"

Comment: Anyway I do not have a list. I have a map of values.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: a `Map` has a `valueSet()` that you can use as input, if you want.